# Spring MVC + Spring Security: how to migrate application from http to https

Tags: spring-mvc, https, spring-security

I have built a spring MVC application using Spring Tool Suite. I also used Spring Security to handle access permissions and login/logout.
The application is currently using http protocol, but I want to move to https completely.

What should I do?
Should I also reconfigure STS' VFabric tc Server to run the appliction? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure your application container if you want to use `https` protocol.

VFabric tc Server docs about SSL:

http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric5/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.6/admin/manual-config-ssl.html

Still you can use Spring Security features. HTTP/HTTPS Channel Security is achieved with `ChannelProcessingFilter`. Fortunately it can be easily configured with Spring Security XML Namespace.

Spring Docs:

> If your application supports both HTTP and HTTPS,  and you require
>   that particular URLs can only be accessed over HTTPS,  then this is
>   directly supported using the requires-channel  attribute on intercept-url

Example Config:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="any"/>
</http>
```

More info: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-requires-channel

Comment: If you want to use HTTPS exclusively I get the container to handle this by setting constraints in web.xml, rather than using Spring Security. Mixing HTTPS and HTTPS is generally not a good idea.

Comment: It that idea included in Spring Sec. Documentation?

Comment: Not that I know of. But it is just part of the servlet spec so it's not really Spring Security specific.

Comment: So at least putting "mixing HTTP and HTTPS is generally not a good idea." in docs would be a nice idea. :)

Comment: It does actually say that. Read the link you posted ;-).

Comment: Luke Taylor, yes I want to use HTTPS only.

Comment: Luke Taylor, what should I add to web.xml?